# What reference to use when you have categorical data and there is no "control" category in Mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data

I have gathered data from 100 participants and want had the data labelled using two different methods. Meaning that I have 2 datasets for each participant, one labelled by method 1 and one by method 2. To give you an overview of the data, it is currently formatted like this:

| participant | label | frequency | method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 23 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 22 | 1 |
| 1 | C | 27 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 13 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | C | 24 | 2 |
| ... | .. | ... | ... |

(There are 100 participants, 7 label categories, the frequency is a continuous variable and there are 2 methods.)

I want to analyze if the method has impact of the frequency of the labels measured. I also want to check for an interaction effect between engine and label.

I thought I should use a linear mixed-effects model like this:

`frequency ~ 1 + label + method + label*method + (1|participant)`

The model itself automatically sets the reference / intercept to Method 2 and Label A (which has the highest overall frequency).

However I am currently running into the problem of what to set as the reference / intercept. as there is no label that is like a ground truth. All these labels are processes that are being measured by the method. And the labels are categorical.

My first question is if a linear mixed effects model can even be used with this kind of data? and my second question is, what to set as a reference when you have categorical data and there is no "control" category to reference?

Answer (score 0):

One common choice for the control or reference category is the most common category.  Another is the one that is either highest or lowest on the dependent variable. Any of these may be best in a particular case.